# Find all the luckest players from the history table using one nested query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, nested

How can we combine two queries into one nested query. let's say we have a relation called history from a game where history: playerid (string), roldid (string), directions(string), year (integer), dice (integer).

**Added more constraints**  but the original question answered  with a working method, but if you know how to do it with out rank() over. please share. trying to the fundamental

```
playerid    roldid     direct       year        dice     
p01         panda       W           2013        6         
p02         bird        N           2014        6         
p03         monkey      S           2013        1         
p01         dog         E           2015        6
p03         monkey      S           2015        4         
p02         cat         S           2015        6         
p04         cat         S           2015        2         
p05         fish        W           2015        4
```

let say we want one nested query that return:

```
p01         6       
p02         6
```

Since throughout the entire game, p01 and p02 always got 6 when they throw a dice.

I know how to do it in two queries but need with to create the one nested query.
two queries:

```
select playerid, sum(dice)/count(*) from history group by playerid;
```

which returns:

```
playerid    sum(dice)/count(*)
p01         6       
p02         6
p03         2.5
p04         2
p05         4
```

Then we can have another query return all the Max s, which happens to be 6 in this case, but it could be both p01,p03  are 4.6 are the Max

What I have try max(sum(dice)/count(*)) doesn't work. any suggestions.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `AVG()` aggregate function and `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT playerid, avg_dice
FROM (
  SELECT playerid, 
         AVG(dice) avg_dice,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(dice) DESC) rnk
  FROM history
  GROUP BY playerid
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Another way to do it without window functions, with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT playerid, 
       AVG(dice) avg_dice
FROM history
GROUP BY playerid
HAVING avg_dice = (SELECT AVG(dice) FROM history GROUP BY playerid ORDER BY AVG(dice) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2421d4fdedb2548318d3617fade82fc2).
Results:

| playerid | avg_dice |
| --- | --- |
| p01 | 6 |
| p02 | 6 |

Comment: Can you please explain a lit? since it does work, but please help me understand better.

Comment: The subquery calculates the average of the column `dice`, with `AVG(dice)` for each player and ranks each player by that average descending. This is done with the window function RANK(). Finally from all the rows that are returned by the subquery only the rows with rank = 1 are returned.

Comment: Can you please explain why you added  the limit 1. It doesn't make a difference on my data set, but would like to know why you add it.

Comment: @Maxfield The subquery: `(SELECT AVG(dice) FROM history GROUP BY playerid ORDER BY AVG(dice))` without `LIMIT 1` returns all the averages of all the playerids. You want only the top average to compare it to `avg_dice` and this is why I use LIMIT 1 and this is how it should be done in standard SQL. But SQLite has a special *feature* and in this case it compares only the top row without LIMIT 1. Any other database would throw an error. You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subquery_expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you want players that only throw 6, you can use aggregation:

```
select h.playerid
from history h
group by h.playerid
having min(dice) = max(dice) and min(dice) = 6;
```

Comment: what if the luckest is 4.5 or 5.4 or 5.9 ?  know 6 ahead of time is not vary practical. Thank you

Comment: @Maxfield . . . This answers the question that you asked which appears to be about "6".  The question doesn't define "luckiest".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(select playerid, sum(dice)/count(*) as ratio_,
        rank() over (partition by playerid order by sum(dice)/count(*) desc) as rn
 from history 
group by playerid) t
Where rn = 1
```

This will return the luckiest person even if there dices are not 6 all the time.

Comment: Select * from
(select playerid, sum(dice)/count(*) as ratio_
        rank() over (partitiin by playerid order by sum(dice)/count(*) desc) as rn
 from history 
group by playerid) t
Where rn = 1. Error: near "rank": syntax error

Comment: This will work in that case as you can see I havr not used hard code 6 in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I meant to comment the other help. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, comma(,) was missing after ratio_. Updated the answer. Please check now.